# How to debug a Quarkus.io application that doesn't stay running

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to run a Quarkus application that was running just fine in dev mode. I had a basic hello-world app. I added a few other resources just to see how that worked. At some point, my app would no longer stay running. It does build successfully (no errors/failures) but won't stay running. (It should be listening on port 3000). I tried running it with

```
mvn compile quarkus:dev -X
```

And while that does produce quite a bit more output, there are no errors. The app just exits. I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this.

Comment: Could you share your app somewhere? Do you have at least one thread marked as a daemon thread?

Comment: I should probably have specified, this is more of a general "how do I" question. In this app's case, it was missing a `@RegisterRestClient` annotation in an interface. But no error was thrown. The app would just exit cleanly.

Comment: Could you provide us a reproducer project? There might be some bug the dev mode that swallows error (there was at least one such bug that was fixed for `0.12.0`)

Comment: Quarkus3 migration is so bad, we had to stick on 2.